# CSS"overflow:scroll;" doesn't work on iOS15

Tags: html, css, ios, safari, webkit

I am currently creating content for a web application.

The content will be generated and placed under a specific div element in the html with the following code.

table elements in that content may extend beyond the content parent element, so I want it to scroll.

Here is that code I tryed.
Forgive me if I put "touch-action:auto" in each tag for environmental reasons of the web app.

```
<div class="global" style="overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto; width: 100%; touch-action: auto;">
    <div class="menu-container" style="touch-action: auto;">
        <div class="header-title">
            <h1 id="title">TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container" style="touch-action: auto;">
            <table class="unit-selection" style="touch-action: auto;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="term">
                        <th id="1st">###</th>
                        <th id="2nd">###</th>
                        <th id="3rd">###</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="data">
                        <td>$$$</td>
                        <td>$$$</td>
                        <td>$$$</td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--Below this are dozens of "<tr>...</tr>"-->
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the CSS codes that will be loaded.

```
    .global {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    border:3px solid blue;
    font-size: 50px;
    }

    table.unit-selection{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin:auto;
        width:90%;
        height: 100%;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 35px 35px;
    }
    
    
    table.unit-selection th {
        background-color:white;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align:center;
        box-shadow: -7px -4px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }
    
    table.unit-selection td {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        background-color:aqua;
        padding:15px;
    }
    
    .unit td {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

It scrolls fine on my windows tablet, but not on my iPad (iOS15).
I researched and implemented solutions on the web, but to no avail.
Please help me.

In addition, I apologize for my poor English　and Code.

Comment: Could you make your code into a SO snippet that we can run.

Comment: I have tried the given code on IOS 15.1 (iPad) and it scrolls fine. Is there something else that might be stopping it?

Comment: @AHaworth Thank you for your comment. I also think that the problem is probably on the web app side, because it does indeed scroll well when the content is displayed by itself. However, I am not able to change the source of the web app. I'm sorry, but do you know of any conditions that prevent scrolling on iOS? Thank you very much for your cooperation.

Comment: @AHaworth However, in the case of Windows and Mac, even if you run it on the web application, it will scroll well.